# Check if YouTube video is playing and run script

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have the following video embeded within WordPress

```
<iframe id="video" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And it's inside a SlideDeck slider, which I want to stop when someone clicks the video. I can't figure out how to get this line of code

```
self.pauseAutoPlay = true;
```

to run when the video is playing.

I desperately need some help please.

**Edit:** As I'm not the end user. I need something that will work with the default embed code from YouTube.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the YouTube iFrame API. Keep in mind, I know just the bare basics of Javascript and so on so this could potentially be a lot more efficient.

You them embed your iframe as you normally would

```
<iframe id="player" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/TJ2X4dFhAC0?enablejsapi" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But with a couple changes. It needs to have an ID, 'player', and you need to append `?enablejsapi` to the end of the source URI.

You'll then need to run the following script to load the API JS as well as creat the player

```
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Notice that `new YT.Player('player'` should match your iframe ID and that `videoId: 'u1zgFlCw8Aw'` should match the src URI.

After this you'll be able to run scripts like

```
var myPlayerState;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          // DO THIS
        }
        myPlayerState = event.data;
      }

if (myPlayerState == 1){
  // PAUSE SLIDER
}
```

Comment: @nicogaldo This answer is about 4 years old at this point. You may want to try search a bit more. Can try looking at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24040526/142410

Answer (score 8):

You need embed youtube direct with flash:

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Embedding

after that, you can use youtube javascript API.

Your code could be something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
<div id="ytapiplayer">
You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
                   "ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);


var player;

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    if (newState == 1)
        callPlay();
    else if (newState == 2)
        callPause();
}

function callPlay() {
    //video is play
}

function callPause() {
    //video is paused
}

</script>
```

P.S. **swfobject.js** soure you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't seem to cooperate with WordPress really good. I'm also hoping for a solution that doesn't require a workaround, as I'm not the end user. I need something that will work with the default embed code from YouTube.

Comment: You can try: [iframe API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Events). But I dont have any experience with that