# Opera and IE7 don't seem to be assigning value to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, youtube-api

Yesterday I asked a question about [running a script once a YouTube video is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8950146/142410) and after **a lot** of wrestling [I figured this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956066/142410var).

Now the solution works in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE9 and IE8 but for some reason it's not working in Opera and IE7. I have very little Javascript experience so any help would be really appreciated.

I link the JS like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.ca/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.ca/wp-content/plugins/slidedeck-lite-for-wordpress/lib/youtubeapi.js?ver=2011-04-28'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.ca/wp-content/plugins/slidedeck-lite-for-wordpress/lib/slidedeck.jquery.lite.js?ver=1.4.5'></script>
```

And within *youtubeapi.js* I run this

```
window.YTplayerState;
    function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
           YTplayerState = evt.data;
    }
```

`window.YTplayerState;` is an attempt to help fix the Opera/IE7 issue. Then within a pre-existing file for the SlideDeck plugin I run this

```
var YTplayerState;
var autoPlay = function() {
    gotoNext = function() {
        if (self.pauseAutoPlay === false) {
            if (self.options.cycle === false && self.current == self.slides.length || YTplayerState == 1) {
                self.pauseAutoPlay = true;
            } else {
                self.next();
            }
            if (YTplayerState == 1) {
                self.pauseAutoPlay = true;
            }
        }
    };

    setInterval(gotoNext, self.options.autoPlayInterval);
};
```

Which most browser seem to be okay with, although that may just be luck, but it works. I know the issue in Opera is that YTplayerState never gets the value because if I manually change the value to one with a keypress function then it all behaves as expected.

If it's not anything with the code directly provided, are there any common quirks with Opera that I should look out for?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is a bug in Youtube video player. Sorry.

If you google for "onPlayerStateChange opera", you'll find more similar error reports.