# Stop all playing iframe videos on click a link javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, iframe

I have a list of iframe videos in my webpage.

```
<iframe width="520" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2muxrT5_a6E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="520" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2muxrT5_a6E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="520" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2muxrT5_a6E" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<a href="#" class="close">Stop all videos</a>
```

I need to stop all playing iframe videos on click the link `Stop all videos`. How can i do that?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try this way,

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(){      
        $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's working fine. But the problem is reloading all videos take a long time. Is there any other way or can i make the reload faster?

Comment: iframes are slower because there is an additional overhead for the browser.

Comment: and your sources are from external site as well

Comment: ok. Thanks a lot. One additional help. How to check the iframe video status that is the video is in playing state or not?

Comment: you need to use YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds. There is a good answer to this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950146/check-if-youtube-video-is-playing-and-run-script and the google reference to the API is here https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: useful, elegant, simple, for anyone who doesnt want to go the youtube js api way

Comment: Note that if you have a different video in each iframe then this won't work - it will change the src of all iframes to the src of the first iframe on page. One of the answers below works better using 'this' keyword.

Comment: language is deprecated

Comment: Just tested this out, works well but all videos src is being replaced by first video src.

Comment: This is a godsend. Thank you!!

Comment: Not really a solution (Like to close Modal on a page by reloading the entire HTML). Speed is matters and also user experience (Users will notice the reload idea - looks more like a bug).

Answer (score 19):

This should stop all videos playing in all iframes on the page:

```
$("iframe").each(function() { 
        var src= $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src',src);  
});
```

Comment: Perfect this code will work with  different videos on a page. thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Reloading all iframes just to stop them is a terrible idea. You should get advantage of what comes with HTML5.

Without using YouTube's iframe_API library; you can simply use:

```
var stopAllYouTubeVideos = () => { 
  var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(iframes, iframe => { 
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'command', 
  func: 'stopVideo' }), '*');
 });
}
stopAllYouTubeVideos();
```

which will stop all YouTubes iframe videos.

You can use these message keywords to start/stop/pause youtube embdded videos:

```
stopVideo
playVideo
pauseVideo
```

Check out the link below for the live demo:

https://codepen.io/mcakir/pen/JpQpwm

**PS-**
**YouTube URL must have `?enablejsapi=1` query parameter to make this solution work.**

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Of all the solutions on this page, only this worked without causing flicker to other animations on page.

Comment: Here's a one liner for stopping one video, that works in MSIE also: document.getElementById('_video').contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ event: 'command', func: 'stopVideo' }), '*');

Answer (score 10):

Stopping means pausing and setting the video to time 0:

```
        $('iframe').contents().find('video').each(function () 
        {
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.pause();
        });
```

This jquery code will do exactly that.

No need to replace the src attribute and reload the video again.

---

Little function that I am using in my project:

```
    function pauseAllVideos() 
    { 
        $('iframe').contents().find('video').each(function () 
        {
            this.pause();
        });
        $('video').each(function () 
        {
            this.pause();
        });
    }
```

Comment: It is denying permission to access 'document'

Comment: It works in all my projects. I have added the function that I am using above.

Comment: The iframe contents and the app must be in the same domain!

Comment: perfect script bro :D

Comment: removing the src and adding it back already resets the video to the start,

Answer (score 9):

Here's a vanilla Javascript solution in 2019

```
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('iframe')
const close = document.querySelector('.close')

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
   videos.forEach(i => {
      const source = i.src
      i.src = ''
      i.src = source
   })
})
```

Comment: great and elegant answer!

Comment: worked for me for multiple videos on same page.

Comment: Its working fine in ReactJS with Bootstrap carousel.

Answer (score 2):

I edited the above code a little and the following worked for me.......

```
<script>
function stop(){<br/>
       var iframe = document.getElementById('myvid');<br/>
     var iframe1 = document.getElementById('myvid1');<br/>
      var iframe2 = document.getElementById('myvid2');<br/>
    iframe.src = iframe.src;<br/>
    iframe1.src=iframe1.src;<br/>
    iframe2.src=iframe2.src;<br/>
}<br/>

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#close").click(function(){
  $("#videoContainer")[0].pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this code with an iteration

```
/**
 * Stop an iframe or HTML5 <video> from playing
 * @param  {Element} element The element that contains the video
 */
var stopVideo = function ( element ) {
    var iframe = element.querySelector( 'iframe');
    var video = element.querySelector( 'video' );
    if ( iframe ) {
        var iframeSrc = iframe.src;
        iframe.src = iframeSrc;
    }
    if ( video ) {
        video.pause();
    }
};
```

OWNER: https://gist.github.com/cferdinandi/9044694
also posted here (by me): [how to destroy bootstrap modal window completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177426/how-to-destroy-bootstrap-modal-window-completely/44717827#44717827)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can **stop iframe or html video,** by using below code.
This will work for single or multiple video on the same page.

```
var  videos = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
 
$(".video-modal .fa-times").on("click", function () {
        videos.forEach(i => {
          let source = i.src;
          i.src = '';
          i.src = source;
       });
        $(".video-modal").css("display", "none");
        return false;
    });

})
```

Comment: this is actually the most hackful ( although the only working for y case ). I'm stuck in a cycle where YT iframe apis are creating players with NO METHODS attached (playVideo, seekTo etc ). I fall back to plain iframe and seems all the postMessage are being blocked by youtube

Answer (score -1):

Reload all iframes again to stop videos

```
<a href="#" class="close" onclick="stop();">Stop all videos</a>

function stop(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('youriframe');
    iframe.src = iframe.src;
}
```

Comment: It's working for single video only. If multiple videos are playing it didn't work.