# stop/reset <iframe> video on click of nav icon

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an image slider element in my html something like this:

```
  <div class="slider">
    <img/>
    <img/>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/"</iframe>
    <img/>
  </div>
```

With an iframe video. Currently it continues to play in the background. I would like to stop/refresh the video when navigating away using the next/prev nav icons (.next and .prev).

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with "Reset"? Pause it? Stop it? Reload it?

Comment: You should use ``<video>`` [HTML5 tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp).

Use [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop) to learn how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You Must Use `video` instead of `iframe`:

```
<video controls>
<source src="Your Path" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[Working **jsfiddle** here](https://jsfiddle.net/687bsb21/44/).

Comment: Is it possible to use the original url from vimeo as the source for the video with html5? Or do I have to have the video saved locally?

Comment: yes you can use url, in the fiddle a url has been used and also you can use both

Answer (score 0):

I used the jquery from this question here : [Stop all playing iframe videos on click a link javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598423/stop-all-playing-iframe-videos-on-click-a-link-javascript)

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('.next , .prev').click(function(){      
                $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
            });
        });
        </script>
```

I attempted to use html5 video, however I encountered problems with using the vimeo url as the source.