# Stop iframe youtube video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I would like to stop playing a youtube video when I click on a div. I don't know how to do this and I do not get it to work when using information online.
This is what I have done!

I have linked the youtube iframe API:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Then I have an iframe in my html file:

```
<iframe id="vid" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/P2lm356ycwY?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then in my script I have this code:

```
$("#popupvid").click(function(){
    $("#popupvid").css("display","none");
    $("#vid").css("display","none");

    //Code to make the youtube video stop here:

});
```

What do I need to write so that the video stops here!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598423/stop-all-playing-iframe-videos-on-click-a-link-javascript

Comment: @mxr7350 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this jquery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function(){
    $('#popupvid').click(function(){      
        $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("iframe").mouseover(function() {
        $("iframe").each(function () {
            $(this)[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*');
        });
    });
});
```

this will stop all videos, change mouse over event to click and the first iframe to the id of your div