# how can I know if a youtube video is playing ? (is it possible in iframe?)

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have an automatic slideshow with images and youtube videos. If a user clicks play on a video, as the slideshow continues running the next slide is shown hence hiding the video.

Is it possible to know if the video is running, as to stop the slideshow from hiding the video?

Thanks...

Comment: Consider using the Youtube API. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956066/638127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how much ease you want, you could use Popcorn.js (https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js). This will let you load web media and then do things on page (whatever you want, change the page, play or pause a slideshow, trigger some JS, etc) based on what happens in the video, as well as letting you query the video's state by using the popcorn API

Comment: excellent to know... I needed something simpler, though... the comment above is just what I needed :)