# Can YouTube be forced to play fullscreen by default on Android?

Tags: android, youtube

The behaviour between YouTube embedded videos and Vimeo embedded videos appears to differ both from each other and across iOS/Android platforms.

I'm displaying the videos within a lightbox provided by a wordpress plugin. The videos are embedded via an iframe which has the `allowfullscreen` attribute.

On an iPhone (using Chrome browser), when the user presses play on either YouTube or Vimeo video, it automatically enters full screen mode.

On an android phone (Samsung Galaxy S6, using Chrome browser), when the user presses play on Vimeo it also automatically enters full screen mode. When the android user presses play on the YouTube video it remains within the lightbox and shows some controls underneath with the option to enter full screen mode.

Here's some screen captures:

**Vimeo**
In the lightbox, before pressing play
[image]

After pressing play Vimeo goes to full screen automatically
[image]

**YouTube**
YouTube video in the lightbox
[image]

After pressing play YouTube does not go full screen automatically (but it does on the iPhone)
[image]

**Question**
Is there a way to make YouTube behave like Vimeo across all devices?

Answer (score 4):

change your code with reference to this:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#video').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="video" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/5iiPC-VGFLU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This forces the video to take up the full width of the screen but doesn't match the functionality as the iOs version, where it's actually the equivalent of clicking the full screen button.

Comment: However, if I tie it in to the player start event as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24040526/563838 this is probably the closest I'm going to get.

Answer (score 0):

It must be the fix to your problem, check this StackOverFlow Answer -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20289540/7125023

**CODEPEN CODE ;**

**HTML**

```
<h1>One-click play+fullscreen via YouTube API</h1>
Suggested code from this <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/20289540/288906">StackOverflow answer</a>

<h2>Instructions</h2>
<ol>
  <li>Click on [play fullscreen]</li>
  <li>Click on the fullscreen button in youtube's player to exit fullscreen</li>
</ol>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<button>play fullscreen</button><br>
<div id="player"></div>

## Safari 8

It works perfectly:

0. Enters fullscreen
0. Exits fullscreen

## Firefox 35

Buggy, annoying but working:

0. Enters fullscreen (on Codepen.io)
0. Enters fullscreen (YouTube.com)
0. Third click: Exits fullscreen

## Chrome 40

Buggy, broken:

0. Enters fullscreen (on Codepen.io)
0. Does nothing
0. Third click: Exits fullscreen but the video fills the iframe, effectively breaking the site. <a href="http://i.imgur.com/CHibfEN.png" target="_blank">Screenshot</a>


## Mobile browsers

This is the default behavior on iPhone, but it cannot work anywhere else (Android, iPad) since 

* to `play()` a video or to `requestFullScreen()` you need a user tap **in the same document** (read: not across the iframe)

This means that

* you can't call `requestFullScreen()` when the video emits the event `onplay`
* you can't trigger `play()` via YouTube API (it would cross the frame) **and** call `requestFullScreen()` in the same tap

So with one tap **either** you play the video **or** get it fullscreen; you'll always need two separate taps if you use YouTube.
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  padding: 1em;
}
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

**MAIN JAVASCRIPT**

```
var player, iframe;
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

// init player
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '200',
    width: '300',
    videoId: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ',
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}

// when ready, wait for clicks
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  var player = event.target;
  iframe = $('#player');
  setupListener(); 
}

function setupListener (){
$('button').addEventListener('click', playFullscreen);
}

function playFullscreen (){
  player.playVideo();//won't work on mobile

  var requestFullScreen = iframe.requestFullScreen || iframe.mozRequestFullScreen || iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen;
  if (requestFullScreen) {
    requestFullScreen.bind(iframe)();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Zotax, so if the user has the latest version of the Youtube app it will work as expected? When you say the Intent is what's calling the App, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm loading the video in an iframe from within the browser.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want it to play on load - I want it to go full screen when the user opts to play the video. The iframe has the allowfullscreen attribute, which I've added to the question

Comment: Isn't this what you're asking for?

Comment: Well I haven't had time to test it yet, but some of the comments in the code don't fill me with confidence: "This is the default behavior on iPhone, but it cannot work anywhere else (Android, iPad)", "player.playVideo();//won't work on mobile". I will check and confirm.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you may use Youtubeapi and check the fullscreen video default but yes there is the fullscreen button on the bottom.

take webview in layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
                 <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                      android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In code section use below code

```
public class YouTubeVideoPlayer extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    public static final String API_KEY = "<creae key from dev consol";


    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "<your youtube video id";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /** attaching layout xml **/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_webview);

        /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

        /** Start buffering **/
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }

    private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
        }

    };

    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I'm including the video via an iframe - this looks like Java? I have no access to any Java code.

Comment: yes this code in java, in my native android app I am using same for my solution

Answer (score 0):

I developed same from this ref. Please check this reference. This will help you.

http://createdineden.com/blog/post/android-tutorial-how-to-integrate-youtube-videos-into-your-app/

For frame less video , check this one:

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/