# Autoplay functionality in youtube video android

Tags: android

I need youtube auto play functionality in my project.I used youtube code for Youtube functionality.Can any body tell me how can i use autoplay functionality

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: Have you used `YouTubeApi` or just `WebView`?

Comment: Please check this. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41955168/3992798

Comment: I used this this link http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/youtubeplayerview-example-in-android-using-youtube-api