# Youtube API detect if autoplay is disabled

Tags: javascript, android, ios, youtube-api

I have used Youtube API to play automatically a video but i have found out that it only works fine on PCs but NOT mobile devices. I did a bit of google-ing and discovered that autoplay feature is disabled on mobile devices.

No the questions is, can i detect if autoplay is disabled ??. Or at least force the video to show youtoube play button if vidio is on state -1.

i.e.

```
if(event.data == -1) {
    // show play button
}
```

Comment: Please vote for autoplay detection: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/79307168

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no way of getting this information without testing with you video and checking whether the video's current time has advanced after it has loaded.

It was asked for as a feature in [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) but as you can see from [this comment](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/353#issuecomment-5644389) from Paul Irish, you have to have a video to check.  It looks like they are trying to add this into v3 of modernizr.

So essentially it is doable and his pseudocode should get you started.  Basically the first four points are done already.  You would just need to implement the last two.

```
create a video element
set video element src to something
add autoplay attribute to it
add element to the dom
bind to that event (something metadata soemthing) that fires when its buffered some
setTimeout after it fires and see if currentTime is > 0
```

Comment: hmm, i was hoping there is a simple / built in solution to this

Comment: I'm afraid not. You could otherwise have the play button there and then when the video begins to play, remove it.  Use the `onPlayerStateChange` callback.  This then handles all play events - whether autoplayed or not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950146/check-if-youtube-video-is-playing-and-run-script

Answer (score 0):

A sample to autoplay without using arg `autoplay`. I only test this solution on PCs not mobile but you can try this code :

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsbin.com/hinaxucovoqo/1/edit?html,js)

**HTML**

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


    var player;
          function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: '390',
              width: '640',
              videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });
          }


          function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
          }

          function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {

            } else {

            }
          }
    function stopVideo() {
            player.stopVideo();
          }
```